Handleproblem with apache2 and PHP-FPM as Unix-Socket
I have been trying to encapsulate the permissions of PHP-FPM with chroot since yesterday.
The current problem is that everything runs under a single PHP-FPM pool, which has the same permissions everywhere. This makes it possible for hosting users to break out of their user/domain directory.
The special feature here is that each user should have an FPM pool, which is then assigned to the respective domains:
Pool-Config
[admin]
prefix = /var/fruithost/users/$pool
listen = .sockets/$pool.sock
access.log = logs/php_access.log
chroot = $prefix
;chdir = /

; Security
user = $pool
group = www-data
listen.owner = $pool
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0600
;listen.acl_users = $pool
;listen.acl_groups = www-data
;listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

; Instances
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3

; Environment Variables
env[TMP] = /tmp
env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
env[TEMP] = /tmp

; Fix Paths
catch_workers_output = yes
php_admin_value[cgi.fix_pathinfo]=1
php_admin_value[cgi.discard_path]=1
php_admin_value[cgi.nph]=1
php_admin_flag[fastcgi.logging] = on
php_admin_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on

The VHost of the respective domain is as follows:
VHost
# Generated by fruithost
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
        AssignUserId admin www-data
    </IfModule>

    ServerAdmin abuse@domain1.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/
    ServerName domain1.tld
    ErrorLog /var/fruithost/users/admin/logs/domain1.tld_error.log
    CustomLog /var/fruithost/users/admin/logs/domain1.tld_access.log combined
    
    # Debugging
    LogLevel trace8
    ProxyErrorOverride Off

    <Directory /var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/>
        Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    <IfModule setenvif_module>
        SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    </IfModule>
    <Proxy "fcgi://domain1.tld/" enablereuse=on max=10>
        ProxySet connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30
    </Proxy>
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
            #ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" DOCUMENT_ROOT "/var/fruithost/users/admin/"
            #ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT "%{reqenv:DOCUMENT_ROOT}"
            #ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" PATH_INFO "%{reqenv:SCRIPT_NAME}"
            #ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" HOME "%{reqenv:DOCUMENT_ROOT}"
            #ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" SCRIPT_NAME "%{reqenv:SCRIPT_NAME}"
            #ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" SCRIPT_FILENAME "%{reqenv:SCRIPT_NAME}"
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/fruithost/users/admin/.sockets/admin.sock|fcgi://domain1.tld"
        </If>
    </FilesMatch>
    
    Header always set AAA_DOCUMENT_ROOT     "expr=%{reqenv:DOCUMENT_ROOT}"
    Header always set AAA_CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT     "expr=%{reqenv:CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT}"
    Header always set AAA_HOME     "expr=%{reqenv:HOME}"
    Header always set AAA_SCRIPT_FILENAME     "expr=%{reqenv:SCRIPT_FILENAME}"
    Header always set AAA_SCRIPT_NAME     "expr=%{reqenv:SCRIPT_NAME}"

    <Files ~ "(^(?!\.fruithost)\.|php\.ini)">
        Require all denied
    </Files>
</VirtualHost>

The problem is the following line:
SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/users/admin.sock"

If I specify ONLY the Unix socket, the PHP is displayed as text/plain source:

However, if I define the whole thing as specified in the documentation (here with |fcgi://localhost):
SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/users/admin.sock|fcgi://localhost"

then I get the following error:

When i've set php_admin_value[cgi.fix_pathinfo]=1, i've get following Error:

My Apache debug headers provide the following values:
AAA_DOCUMENT_ROOT:          /var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/
AAA_CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT:  /var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/
AAA_HOME: 
AAA_SCRIPT_FILENAME:        /index.php
AAA_SCRIPT_NAME:            /index.php

And I don't know:

Why is the source of the PHP file displayed although the Unix socket is specified?
What is |fcgi://localhost explicitly used for? it is not described anywhere? How does the mechanics behind it work? Is this a fall-back or some kind of post-processing?

The error messages in the log files are just like spooning soup with a roll of toilet paper.
[Sun Sep 01 11:58:11.768628 2024] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2673:tid 2673] [client 172.23.208.1:65397] AH01071: Got error 'Unable to open primary script: /index.php (No such file or directory)', referer: http://my.debian/

If I adjust the variable SCRIPT_FILENAME:
ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" SCRIPT_FILENAME "%{reqenv:DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{reqenv:SCRIPT_NAME}"

Does the error message change with the respective path, but I don't understand how the context is merged, because DOCUMENT_ROOT is already in the focus context, so I don't actually have to specify it for SCRIPT_FILENAME?
[Sun Sep 01 11:45:55.291101 2024] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2485:tid 2485] [client 172.23.208.1:64401] AH01071: Got error 'Unable to open primary script: /var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/index.php (No such file or directory)', referer: http://my.debian/

Edit
Here is a detailed logfile of an request:
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464373 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_request.c(435): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] Headers received from client:
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464389 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_request.c(438): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   Host: domain1.tld
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464393 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_request.c(438): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   Connection: keep-alive
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464396 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_request.c(438): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   Cache-Control: max-age=0
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464409 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_request.c(438): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464412 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_request.c(438): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/112.0.0.0
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464415 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_request.c(438): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464429 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_request.c(438): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464432 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_request.c(438): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464548 2024] [core:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] util_expr_eval.c(863): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] Evaluation of expression from /etc/fruithost/config/apache2/vhosts/10_domain1.tld.conf:52 gave: 1
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464705 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464712 2024] [authz_core:debug] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464716 2024] [core:trace3] [pid 11456:tid 11456] request.c(360): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /index.php
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464785 2024] [proxy:trace2] [pid 11456:tid 11456] proxy_util.c(2457): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] *: fixup UDS from proxy:unix:/var/fruithost/users/admin/.sockets/admin.sock|fcgi://domain1.tld/var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/index.php: fcgi://domain1.tld/var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/index.php (/var/fruithost/users/admin/.sockets/admin.sock)
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464806 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace1] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(76): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] canonicalising URL //domain1.tld/var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/index.php
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464813 2024] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(123): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01060: set r->filename to proxy:fcgi://domain1.tld/var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/index.php
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464818 2024] [proxy:trace2] [pid 11456:tid 11456] proxy_util.c(2604): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] fcgi: found worker fcgi://domain1.tld/ for fcgi://domain1.tld/var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/index.php
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464821 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy.c(1465): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01143: Running scheme fcgi handler (attempt 0)
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464825 2024] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1078): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01076: url: fcgi://domain1.tld/var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/index.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464828 2024] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1087): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01078: serving URL fcgi://domain1.tld/var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/index.php
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464834 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 11456:tid 11456] proxy_util.c(2797): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (domain1.tld:8000)
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464853 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 11456:tid 11456] proxy_util.c(3242): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH00944: connecting fcgi://domain1.tld/var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/index.php to domain1.tld:8000
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464859 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 11456:tid 11456] proxy_util.c(3309): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH02545: fcgi: has determined UDS as /var/fruithost/users/admin/.sockets/admin.sock (for domain1.tld:8000)
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464864 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 11456:tid 11456] proxy_util.c(3450): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH00947: connecting /var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/index.php to /var/fruithost/users/admin/.sockets/admin.sock:0 (domain1.tld:8000)
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464914 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 11456:tid 11456] proxy_util.c(3832): AH02823: FCGI: connection established with Unix domain socket /var/fruithost/users/admin/.sockets/admin.sock (domain1.tld:8000)
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464948 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'HTTP_HOST' value 'domain1.tld'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464952 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'HTTP_CONNECTION' value 'keep-alive'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464955 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' value 'max-age=0'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464958 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS' value '1'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464961 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' value 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/112.0.0.0'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464964 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'HTTP_ACCEPT' value 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464967 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' value 'gzip, deflate'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464970 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' value 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464973 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'PATH' value '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464976 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'SERVER_SIGNATURE' value ''
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464979 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'SERVER_SOFTWARE' value 'Apache'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464982 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'SERVER_NAME' value 'domain1.tld'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464985 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'SERVER_ADDR' value '172.23.222.189'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464988 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'SERVER_PORT' value '80'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464991 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'REMOTE_ADDR' value '172.23.208.1'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.464998 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' value '/var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465001 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'REQUEST_SCHEME' value 'http'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465004 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'CONTEXT_PREFIX' value ''
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465007 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT' value '/var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465010 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'SERVER_ADMIN' value 'abuse@domain1.tld'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465013 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'SCRIPT_FILENAME' value 'proxy:fcgi://domain1.tld/var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/index.php'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465016 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'REMOTE_PORT' value '65508'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465019 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' value 'CGI/1.1'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465021 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' value 'HTTP/1.1'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465024 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'REQUEST_METHOD' value 'GET'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465027 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'QUERY_STRING' value ''
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465030 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'REQUEST_URI' value '/index.php'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465033 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(411): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01062: sending env var 'SCRIPT_NAME' value '/index.php'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465316 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(724): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] FastCGI header (8 bytes)
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465329 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(724): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] ........         0107000100160200                
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465345 2024] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 11456:tid 11456] [client 172.23.208.1:65508] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465364 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(724): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] FastCGI header (8 bytes)
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465379 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(724): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] .....Q..         0106000100510700                
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465392 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] util_script.c(572): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] Headers from script 'index.php':
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465399 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] util_script.c(575): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   Status: 404 Not Found
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465404 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace1] [pid 11456:tid 11456] util_script.c(654): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] Status line from script 'index.php': 404 Not Found
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465408 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] util_script.c(575): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465417 2024] [headers:trace2] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_headers.c(865): AH01502: headers: ap_headers_output_filter()
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465426 2024] [headers:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] util_expr_eval.c(847): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] Evaluation of string expression from /etc/fruithost/config/apache2/vhosts/10_domain1.tld.conf:63 gave: /var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465431 2024] [headers:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] util_expr_eval.c(847): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] Evaluation of string expression from /etc/fruithost/config/apache2/vhosts/10_domain1.tld.conf:64 gave: /var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465435 2024] [headers:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] util_expr_eval.c(847): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] Evaluation of string expression from /etc/fruithost/config/apache2/vhosts/10_domain1.tld.conf:65 gave: 
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465438 2024] [headers:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] util_expr_eval.c(847): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] Evaluation of string expression from /etc/fruithost/config/apache2/vhosts/10_domain1.tld.conf:66 gave: proxy:fcgi://domain1.tld/var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/index.php
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465442 2024] [headers:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] util_expr_eval.c(847): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] Evaluation of string expression from /etc/fruithost/config/apache2/vhosts/10_domain1.tld.conf:67 gave: /index.php
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465471 2024] [http:trace3] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_filters.c(1141): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] Response sent with status 404, headers:
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465476 2024] [http:trace5] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_filters.c(1150): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   Date: Sun, 01 Sep 2024 13:40:00 GMT
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465479 2024] [http:trace5] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_filters.c(1153): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   Server: fruithost
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465482 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_filters.c(971): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   AAA_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465485 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_filters.c(971): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   AAA_CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465488 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_filters.c(971): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   AAA_HOME: 
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465491 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_filters.c(971): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   AAA_SCRIPT_FILENAME: proxy:fcgi://domain1.tld/var/fruithost/users/admin/domain1.tld/index.php
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465494 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_filters.c(971): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   AAA_SCRIPT_NAME: /index.php
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465497 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_filters.c(971): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465500 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_filters.c(971): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   Connection: Keep-Alive
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465503 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_filters.c(971): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465505 2024] [http:trace4] [pid 11456:tid 11456] http_filters.c(971): [client 172.23.208.1:65508]   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465539 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(724): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] FastCGI header (8 bytes)
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465543 2024] [proxy_fcgi:trace8] [pid 11456:tid 11456] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(724): [client 172.23.208.1:65508] ........         0103000100080000                
[Sun Sep 01 15:40:00.465582 2024] [proxy:debug] [pid 11456:tid 11456] proxy_util.c(2813): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (domain1.tld:8000)

